# VBA workout how many days, hours, minutes or seconds between two timestamps?

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I am trying to display the number of days or hours or minutes or seconds between two timestamps using vba.

So far my code gives me the number of hours or days.

```
Sub Date_Dif()

    Dim d1 As Date
    d1 = Range("A8").Value

    Dim d2 As Date
    d2 = Now

    Dim hrsDiff As Long
    hrsDiff = DateDiff("h", d1, d2)

    ActiveSheet.Range("Z5").Value = IIf(hrsDiff >= 24, _
               hrsDiff \ 24 & " days " & hrsDiff Mod 24 & " hours", _
               hrsDiff & " hours")

End Sub
```

How can I adapt this to give me minutes or seconds as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to subtract the dates and use the `Hour`, `Minute`, and `Second` functions.  Since `Date` variables are stored as a `Double` with the integer portion representing days since epoch, you can use that directly for days after a subtraction:

```
Dim diff As Date
diff = Now - #7/7/2016 2:15:16 PM#
Debug.Print CLng(Int(diff)) & " days"
Debug.Print Hour(diff) & " hours"
Debug.Print Minute(diff) & " minutes"
Debug.Print Second(diff) & " seconds"
```

Plug that into your `Sub` and you get something like this:

```
Sub Date_Dif()

    Dim d1 As Date
    d1 = Range("A8").Value

    Dim diff As Date
    diff = Now - d1

    ActiveSheet.Range("Z5").Value = _
               CLng(Int(diff)) & " days " & _
               Hour(diff) & " hours " & _
               Minute(diff) & " minutes " & _
               Second(diff) & " seconds"
End Sub
```

Comment: `clng` is a numeric conversion function that drops thousand separator, precision - 1 instead of 1.22 - and currency symbols. If you only want minutes, `minute` here seems the wrong one as it is related to hours and days if I am right. instead use  `datediff("n","start","end")`.